# If p does not divide a and p does not divide k, than p does not divide a*k

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can I prove that:

If $p$ (prime) does not divide $a$ and $p$ does not divide $k$, than $p$ does not divide $a*k$?

Does this follow from Euclid's lemma?
$$\forall a,b\in \Bbb Z~:~ p\text{ prime}\implies \left(p\mid ab \implies (p\mid a\vee p\mid b)\right)$$

Comment: Contrapositive follows the truth value of..

Comment: [Here's how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question); in particular, we use MathJax here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, any statement of the form $(A\wedge B)\to C$ is equivalent to $A\to(B\to C)$. (This rule of equivalence is known as "exportation".)

So Euclid's Lemma can be stated: $$\forall a,b\in \Bbb Z~:~ p\text{ priem}\implies (p\mid ab \implies (p\mid a\vee p\mid b))$$

Thus if we substitute the contrapositive for that inner nested implication (and use deMorgan's Law):
$$\forall a,b\in \Bbb Z~:~ p\text{ priem}\implies ((p\nmid a\wedge p\nmid b)\implies p\nmid ab)$$

And via exportation again we have
$$\forall a,b\in \Bbb Z~:~ (p\text{ priem}\wedge p\nmid a\wedge p\nmid b) \implies p\nmid ab$$

Thus the statement, "If $p$ (a prime) does not divide $a$ (an integer) and does not divide $b$ (an integer), then $p$ does not divide their product, $ab$," is *logically equivalent to* Euclid's Lemma .

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is in fact the contrapositive. If $p$, being prime, divided $a \times k$, it would imply from Euclid's lemma that $p$ divides either $a$ or $k$. Since neither is the case, then $p$ cannot divide $a \times k$.

Comment: Thanks, I just had some trouble with the contrapositive of p prime. But p stays always prime in the normal statement and the contrapositive?

Comment: Yeah, the actual, formal contrapositive would be that "either $p$ does not divide $ak$ or $p$ isn't prime", but since you know that $p$ is prime then it must be the other.

Comment: $(A\wedge\neg C)\to\neg B$ can be considered *a* contraposition of $(A\wedge B)\to C$, though to be precise $\neg C\to(\neg A\vee\neg B)$ is *the* contrapositive.  In any case, all three statements are considered equivalent, so proving one proves the others.

Comment: @GrahamKemp But (A∧¬C)→¬B is not the same as ¬C→(¬A∨¬B) ?

Comment: They are equivalent. @WinstonCherf